# Install Rmpfr package in RStudio on remote server

Tags: r, redhat, rstudio-server, mpfr

I often use R / RStudio that is located on a remote server. Unfortunately, I do not have root / sudo / administrator access on this server, so any installations need to be done only in ~/.

I know that Rmpfr relies on libmpfr4 and mpfr.h. I have mpfr and gmp installed on my local folder (~/), but it seems R / RStudio only knows to look in /usr. I have tried the following command:

```
install.packages("Rmpfr", type = "source", configure.args = c("--with-mpfr-include=~/include", "--with-mpfr-lib=~/lib"))
```

and I got the following error:

```
In file included from Ops.c:12:0:
Rmpfr_utils.h:22:18: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <mpfr.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Ops.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rmpfr’
```

I confirmed that mpfr.h is in the "~/include" folder and libmpfr.a is in the "~/lib" folder. I also have all of the following in my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="~/mpfr-4.1.0/src/:$PATH"
export PATH="~/bin/:$PATH"
export PATH="~/gmp-6.2.1/:$PATH"
```

I'm pretty far out of my element with the more technical Linux / command line stuff, but I'm trying to learn and use Google / manuals as much as possible. My server runs a redhat distro. For some reason, `apt-get` doesn't seem to be a valid command on my server, `yum` requires root access that I don't have, and I can't figure out how to install homebrew for any `brew` solutions.

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information. Thanks in advance.